# How to find unavailable entities in couchbase while using RxJava?

Tags: rx-java, couchbase

**Requirement :** Bulk read a bunch of objects from couchbase. Even if one object is unavailable throw an exception with a message stating that the following objects are unavailable.

**Approach :** We are using the RxJava and asyncBucket to read these objects from the DB.

**Code :**

```
        final List<String> failedToReadOrders = new ArrayList<>();
        final List<Order> list = Observable
                .from(ids)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .flatMap(id -> asyncBucket
                        .get(id)
                        .doOnError(ex-> {
                            failedToReadOrders.add(id);
                            LOGGER.error("Error occured while reading order with ID key={}",id);
                            })
                        .retryWhen(retryFunc())
                        .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty()))
                .map(doc-> couchbaseConversionService.convertJsonToJavaObject(doc.content(), Order.class))
                .toList()
                .toBlocking()
                .single();
```

The doOnError method is only called if their is any exception thrown by the asyncBucket.get() method. However if the item is not available, then the asyncBucket.get() documentation says that "If the document is not found, the Observable completes without an item emitted.".

**Question :** I can of-course know which items were not read by finding a diff between the ids list to read and the objects returned. However, is it possible to collect these ids in the above code itself so that I don't have to loop on the list again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<Order> list = Observable
    .from(ids)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .flatMap(id -> asyncBucket
        .get(id)
        .switchIfEmpty(Observable.error(new Throwable("No data found")))
        .doOnError(ex-> {
            failedToReadOrders.add(id);
            LOGGER.error("Error occured while reading order with ID key={}",id);
        })
        .retryWhen(retryFunc())
        .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty()))
    .map(doc-> couchbaseConversionService.convertJsonToJavaObject(doc.content(), Order.class))
    .toList()
    .toBlocking()
    .single();
```

Comment: We have to throw exception if the object is unavailable in the DB for a given ID in the list. Your code throws exception if the ID itself is null. We will never have null IDs to search.

Comment: Basically you can use switchIfEmpty() to throw exception. Since observable returns nothing when no record found.

Comment: Great that works. Can we also collect the ids of objects not present in the DB in a list? For ex. in the above code we are collecting failedToReadOrders. In the same I would like to collect the unavailable Ids in a list.

Comment: I will update the code with the changes asked. Let me know if it worked.

Comment: No I get the following compilation error : The method switchIfEmpty(Observable<? extends JsonDocument>) in the type Observable<JsonDocument> is not applicable for the arguments ((<no 
  type> id) -> {})
 - The target type of this expression must be a functional interface